# antlr4 not parsing according to grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm trying to parse 'for loop' according to this (partial) grammar:

```
grammar GaleugParserNew;

/*
 * PARSER RULES
 */

relational 
: '>'
| '<'
;

varChange
: '++'
| '--'
;

values
: ID
| DIGIT
;

for_stat
: FOR '(' ID '=' values ';' values relational values ';' ID varChange ')' '{' '}'  
;

/*
 * LEXER RULES
 */

 FOR    : 'for' ;

 ID     : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z_0-9]* ;
 DIGIT  : [0-9]+ ;

 SPACE  : [ \t\r\n] -> skip ;
```

When I try to generate the gui of how it's parsed, it's not following the grammar I provided above. This is what it produces:

[image]

I've encountered this problem before, what I did then was simply exit cmd, open it again and compile everything and somehow that worked then. It's not working now though.

I'm not really very knowledgeable about antlr4 so I'm not sure where to look to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be a problem of the IDE you are using. The grammar is fine and produces this parse tree in Visual Studio Code:

[image: Parse tree for the given grammar]

I guess the IDE is using the wrong parser or lexer (maybe from a different work file?). Print the lexer tokens to see if they are what you expect. Hint: avoid defining implicit lexer tokens (like '(', '}' etc.), which will allow to give the tokens good names.

Comment: Mike, I see you wrote the VS plugin: looks nice!

Comment: And even better: since this is SVG you can style it with your own CSS (fonts, colors, corner radius, but not the shapes as such).